# relating $\hat {p}$ to $\bar{x} $

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to develop an intuitive understanding of the relationship between $\hat{p}$ and $\bar{x}$. Please point out anything that is incorrect.

For a Bernoulli distribution, if $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ all have mean, $\mu$, and all have the same variance, $\sigma^2$,then the sampling distribution has the following properties:

$\bar{X} = { \sum \limits_{i=1}^n X_i \over n}$

$E(\bar{X}) = \mu$

$Var(X) = \sigma^2 = p(1-p)$, shown by applying the formula, $Var(X)= \sum\limits_{x=0}^1(x-E(x))^2p(x)$

$Var(\bar {X}) = {\sigma^2 \over n} = \frac{p(1-p)}{n} = Var(\hat{p})$

So we can conclude that the variance of the mean of the sampling distribution, $\bar{X}$, is the same as the variance of the population proportion, $\hat{p}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely the estimator of $p$, namely $\hat p$, is defined as being equal to the sample mean $\bar X$? Given this, of course it has the same variance, because it's the same thing!

Your calculations look correct to me.